# Bootstrap mobile menu on fixed sized header being cut off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with a menu on a webpage I am developing for a friend. This is my first bootstrap webpage, so I'm still getting the hang of it.

The menu works fine until it is in mobile view size, then gets cut off. I have a fixed size header that the menu is sitting in, and I'm guessing this is why it is being cut off; however, I have tried not having that and I then lose my background. Happy to modify the header or the menu. Any suggestions?

Not sure what parts of my CSS and HTML to share that would be useful.

Here's the page: http://www.endure.com.au/bgp.html

Comment: Have you tried overflow:scroll property??

Comment: I haven't tried that, but when you click the menu button you don't even see half of the first word, so I'm not sure that it would work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i tried it worked..try this

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
  z-index:9999999;
  background-color:"white"
  }
  .dropdown {
   z-index: 99999999;
   background-color: any color that is makes visible your menu;
   }
```

Comment: That's helped a lot, you can see it now, which is great. But when you scroll over it shows what is underneath, so the menu is not actually functional. I have re-uploaded with your suggested edits and have made them as a media query.

Comment: menu is functional only but its not visible. try to apply same property to sub menus too..!

Comment: i have edited my answer for all property of menus..!